# distinguish the columns of a stacked column chart

Tags: c#

I want to draw a stacked chart from mysql database.
I want to have 4 columns named "port1", "port2", "port3" and "port4".

My problem is when I import the data from my DB, I check the type a column in the table then I draw the chart . My DB contains 4 types of port consequently I would have 4 columns named port1, port2, port3 and port4, but my code generate all the data but on the same column which is port1.

How can I add an identical number of datapoints?

[image: This is a part of my code]

```
try
{   
    con.Open();

    string query1 = "SELECT type,name,value FROM " + server + " WHERE type LIKE '%port1'" ;                             
    string query4 = "SELECT type,name,value FROM " + server + " WHERE type LIKE '%port4'";
    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);              
    SqlCommand cmmd4 = new SqlCommand(query4, con);
    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dataReader.Read())  
    {
        chart1.Series.Add(dataReader["name"].ToString());
        chart1.Series[dataReader["name"].ToString()].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        chart1.Series[dataReader["name"].ToString()]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";                
        chart1.Series[dataReader["name"].ToString()].Points.AddXY((dataReader["type"].ToString()), dataReader["value"].ToString()); 
    }  

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
}
```

Comment: Your 'question' is rather unclear. where is the problem? Writing the sql or setting up the chart or adding the data ? or binding it? - 'columns' in a stacked chart are created by having different x-values. Your strings 'port1'.. are ok but not ideal for that. You stack the values or various series onto one another by letting them have the very same __numeric__ x-values. since your x-values don't have numeric values you will __need__ to add an identical number of datapoints for each series or else they won't match.

Comment: my problem is when I import the data from my DB, I check the type a column in the table then I draw the chart . My DB contains 4 types of port consequently I would have 4 columns named port1, port2, port3 and port4 but my code generate all the data but on the same column which is port1

Comment: how can I add an identical number of datapoints?

Comment: You don't show all the code right? I see only one reader but two selects? (no need to alwqys show all code but it helps to indicate what is left out..!) - Instead of creating the same number of datapoints it is easier to add numeric x-values and set the labels as needed..

Comment: this is all the code

Answer (score 0):

try
            {

```
            con.Open();

            string query1 = "SELECT type,name,value FROM " + server + " WHERE type LIKE '%port1'" ;                                      
            SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);              
            SqlDataReader dataReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
               {

                chart1.Series.Add(dataReader["name"].ToString());
                chart1.Series[dataReader["name"].ToString()].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
                chart1.Series[dataReader["name"].ToString()]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";                
                chart1.Series[dataReader["name"].ToString()].Points.AddXY((dataReader["type"].ToString()), dataReader["value"].ToString());                    

               }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
         }



        try
        {

            con.Open();
            string query2 = "SELECT type,name,value FROM " + server + " WHERE type LIKE '%port2'";
            SqlCommand cmmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
            SqlDataReader dataReader2 = cmmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader2.Read())
            {

                chart1.Series.Add(dataReader2["name"].ToString());

                chart1.Series[dataReader2["name"].ToString()].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
                chart1.Series[dataReader2["name"].ToString()]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group2";
                // MessageBox.Show(dataReader2["type"].ToString());
               chart1.DataBind();
                chart1.Series[dataReader2["name"].ToString()].Points.AddXY("Port_2", dataReader2["value"].ToString());
                chart1.Series[dataReader2["name"].ToString()]["PointWidth"] = "1";

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error "+ ex);
        }
```